# configuring the log4cplus ConversionPattern for different log level

Tags: logging, log4cplus

i would like to configure different pattern for diff level on the same file
e.g.

INFO or DEBUG i dont need to show filename or line number

> conversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c - %m %n

WARN or FATAL - I need to show filename or line number

> ConversionPattern=%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S} [%t] %-5p %c{2} %%%x%% - %m [%l]%n

how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No current version of log4cplus supports that. You could get similar effect by using two different appenders with [log level filters](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1spi_1_1LogLevelRangeFilter.html) [attached](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1Appender.html#af1098f3d19e813d88b7d899f9720e4a5).

Comment: It's kind of useful feature. you would want to show more for error. But, just keeep it simple for debug output only...